# Load incomplete text file into using SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have a large text file with 7 columns with delimited pipe symbol (|). I need to load into table using SSIS. There are few rows in text file has no data for last column. Since it is not having data, it is just loading the last column as entire row.
For example

```
Id|name|lastname|firstname|sal|Email
1 |AABB|AA|BB|20|abc@gmail.com
2|XYZ|X|YZ|30
```

In this 2nd row I don't have data for email column and not ended with | symbol.
After loaded the data into table and data looks like

```
 1 AABB AA BB 20 abc@gmail.com
 2 XYZ  X  YZ 30 XYZ|X|YZ|30
```

Ideally it should load as blank or NULL for the 2nd row. But it is not happening.

Can anyone suggest me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Hi All, Could anyone suggest solution for this.

Comment: I'd 1st suggest that you ask for a properly formatted file. 2nd, if you have to process it then I would use c# as a source using a split function. And then have a switch statement to handle whether you have 5 or 6 columns.

Comment: A. Try ragged right format. B. Load into as a single line (with no column delimiter) and use some other mechanism to split. My preference is to load into a staging table and use T-SQL but a C# script is equally valid, depending on which you prefer. Here's what I get when I google _SSIS Ragged Right_ https://www.sqlshack.com/working-with-ragged-right-formatted-files-in-ssis/